# Stub unimplemented method in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm testing my module and I decided to test it versus anonymous class:

```
  subject(:klass) { Class.new { include MyModule } }
```

`MyModule` uses method `name` inside `klass`. To let my specs work I need to stub this method `name` (which is unimplemented). So I wrote:

```
subject { klass.new }
allow(subject).to receive(:name).and_return('SOreadytohelp') }
```

but it raises:

```
 RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<#<Class:0x007feb67a17750>:0x007feb67c7adf8> does not implement: name
from spec-support-3.3.0/lib/rspec/support.rb:86:in `block in <module:Support>'
```

how to stub this method without defining it?

Comment: I don't know if it is the answer but you have a typo; `subjet { klass.new }`. Shouldn't it be: `subject { klass.new }` (missing a 'c'). Try that and let us know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RSpec raises this exception because it is not useful to stub a method that does not exist on the original object.

Mocking methods is always error-prone because the mock might behave differently than the original implementation and therefore specs might be successful even if the original implementation would have returned an error (or does not even exist). Allowing to mock non-existing methods is just plain wrong.

Therefore I would argue that you should not try to bypass this exception. Just add a `name` method to your class that raises a clear exception if run outside of the test environment:

```
def self.name
  raise NoMethodError  # TODO: check specs...
end
```

Comment: `name` should probably be an instance method returning `'SOreadytohelp'`

Comment: @Stefan: I agree, that is also a good idea. Depends on the focus: To stress that specs and code are in sync or that there is something to fix...

Comment: definition of NotImplementedError : 

`NotImplementedError

Raised when a feature is not implemented on the current platform. For example, methods depending on the +fsync+ or +fork+ system calls may raise this exception if the underlying operating system or Ruby runtime does not support them.`

it should be 
`NoMethodError` : 
`Raised when a method is called on a receiver which doesn’t have it defined and also fails to respond with +method_missing+`

Correction needed

Answer (score 3):

```
subject(:klass) do 
  Struct.new(:name) do
   include MyModule
  end
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that if the test you're writing is focused on your `MyModule` module, and that module relies on an instance method in the class that it is mixed into, then I think that method should be mocked out in the anonymous class that you use when testing the module.  For example:

```
module MyModule
  def call_name
    # expected implementation of #name to be
    # in the class this module is mixed into
    name
  end
end

RSpec.describe MyModule do
  let(:my_module_able) do
    Class.new do
      include MyModule

      # We don't care what the return value of this method is;
      # we just need this anonymous class to respond to #name
      def name
        'Some Name that is not SOReadytohelp'
      end
    end.new
  end

  describe '#call_name' do
    let(:name) { 'SOReadytohelp' }

    before do
      allow(my_module_able).to receive(:name).and_return(name)
    end

    it 'returns the name' do
      expect(my_module_able.call_name).to eq(name)
    end
  end
end
```