# How can you stub a method on an OpenStruct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have an rspec test that does the following:

```
  enrollment_hash = {
      checked_dependents: []
  }
  enrollment = OpenStruct.new enrollment_hash

  org_plan_response.new(enrollment)
```

and in the org_plan_response I have:

```
@enrollment.requires_termination_reason?(x, y)
```

I would like to stub out the requires_termination_reason in the test but can't figure it out.

I tried: `enrollment.stub(:requires_termination_reason?).with('x', 'y').and_return { false }`

but get:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `stub' for #< OpenStruct checked_dependents=[]>

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349503/stub-unimplemented-method-in-rspec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'ostruct'

describe "" do
  specify "" do
    enrollment = OpenStruct.new(checked_dependents: [])

    allow(enrollment).to receive(:requires_termination_reason?).with('x', 'y').and_return(false)

    expect(enrollment.requires_termination_reason?('x', 'y')).to be false
  end
end
```

The above code works for me. Be careful to ensure that the `enrollment` object with the stub is the same one that is used in the test.

Comment: Presumably something has changed in the intervening time, as this currently produces `#<OpenStruct checked_dependents=[]> does not implement: requires_termination_reason?`